# how to find all numbers that there distance from given point are less or equall to integer n

Tags: search, tree, computer-science, nearest-neighbor

given a set of points D and some number K I want to find all numbers that are in D such that the distance between K and any found number is less or equal to integer N?

Example:
suppose we have D={5,9,0,6,7} and K=8 and N=1 then the result should be {9,7}

I was thinking to use k-d tree or VP tree but both as I understand (correct me if I am wrong please) find nearest neighbors and do not care about N in my example.

Comment: @dWinder I am just exploring possible methods excluding brute searching so no time complexity constrains

Comment: if so why no iterate on set D and check each point? this can be done on `O(n)` which is pretty good most of the time - I mean do you search for method lower then `O(n)`? Can you pre-process as sorting D? this will give `O(logn+answer size)`

Comment: @dWinder suppose I have extremely large data set I am looking for better solution maybe something like VP trees or so

Comment: pre-processing is possible but allow me to explain better what I am trying to find: for large dataset instead of iterating on each element in D I want and algorithm that eleminate large number of elements that needs not to be compared to the n

Comment: Using VP tree will be same time complexity (build the tree at `n*logn` and search at `logn` same as simple array)

Comment: that is great note I did not pay attention to thank you for pointing me out to it

Comment: @dWinder please explain to me more about your suggested approach applying it to my example noting that preprocessing is possible in answer to accept

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize all the comment:

Solve this problem as brute force will take `O(n)` time as iterate on each element in D and check if its distance from `k` is less then `n`.

You have big data set but a lot of queries it is better to do pre-processing on D (with `O(nlogn)` and the you can get the answer in `O(logn)` -> by sorting D as pre-processes (in `O(nlogn)` as dimple sort of array.

Now, on given query search for `k` - notice binary search will stop if the number missing but he **do** stop at the closest value. From that index start spread to both side of D and for each check if still in `n` range. Notice the spreading in allow as it is include of `O(|output|)`.

In your example: sorted `D` yield: `[0,5,6,7,9]`. Try finding `k=8` will give false but index 3 or 4 (depended on the implementation). Let say is return index 3. for 3 till last index check if `arr[i] - k < n` if so print - if bigger **stop**. For the other side check `k - arr[i] < n` - if so print and if bigger **stop** -> this will give you `7,9`

Hope that helps!